# Download file from binary array on a webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have file in the form of binary array and i need the browser to open a download dialogue and save the file.

i tried

```
Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
```

but it just added the binary character to the page and didn't open a download dialogue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileToDownload");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also to set the content type:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```